# Scalable way to ask for special and runtime permissions in one go

Tags: android, kotlin, solid-principles, runtime-permissions

I'm creating a feature which uses two permissions

1. SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM - Special Permission (Need to direct the user to settings screen via Intent)
2. POST_NOTIFICATIONS - Runtime Permission (Can be handled by using rememberLauncherForActivityResult()

The main issue is that I have to handle cases 4 cases

1. both are granted
2. None of them is granted
3. SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM is granted POST_NOTIFICATIONS is denied
4. POST_NOTIFICATIONS is granted SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM is denied

How to the achieve the above in an elegant way first and then if possible devise a scalable way for the same.

I was able to achieve my goal but the code I wrote is too tightly coupled and doesn't follows SOLID principles.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.